# Change a field in Database on a Particular Date

Tags: sql-server, update

There is a field in my database named **GRADES**, what I want to accomplish is that on a particular date I want to update all the grades of a specific value to a new value. For example, let's say 5 weeks from today's date I want to update **Grades** from **I** to **F**.

Thanks in Advance

**Note:** I cannot do anything to the database like create a new table or a new field  it should be in the same table.

Comment: Update Table set Grades = 'F' Where Grades = 'I'     --to do this on a later date, schedule a job with the Update statement in it.  Or am I missing the point of the question?

Comment: No you are right, i haven't tried but your solution will work but want it through C# application if possible

Comment: the application you use is still going to either send that update statement or call a stored proc that contains it.  C#, Python, whatever.  How you schedule is just a matter of preference

Answer (score 1):

If I were starting from scratch, I might build this logic into a computed column. This may not be the best idea, but I figured I'd throw it out there as an alternative.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Grades
(
    StudentiD BIGINT,
    CourseId BIGINT,
    CourseGrade VARCHAR(2),
    FailDate DATE,
    FinalGrade AS CASE WHEN GETDATE() >= FailDate
                            AND CourseGrade = 'I' THEN 'F'
                       ELSE CourseGrade
                  END
);
```

When data gets inserted, you can have a default for (and a modifiable by teachers/admins) `FailDate`.

```
INSERT dbo.Grades ( StudentiD, CourseId, CourseGrade, FailDate )
VALUES ( 1, 1, 'A', GETDATE() )

INSERT dbo.Grades ( StudentiD, CourseId, CourseGrade, FailDate )
VALUES ( 1, 2, 'I', GETDATE() )

INSERT dbo.Grades ( StudentiD, CourseId, CourseGrade, FailDate )
VALUES ( 1, 3, 'B', GETDATE() )

INSERT dbo.Grades ( StudentiD, CourseId, CourseGrade, FailDate )
VALUES ( 1, 4, 'I', GETDATE() )

INSERT dbo.Grades ( StudentiD, CourseId, CourseGrade, FailDate )
VALUES ( 1, 5, 'C', GETDATE() )
```

This allows them to give extensions or permanently get rid of the concept by making the value `NULL`.

So the query

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Grades AS g
```

Gives us:

```
StudentiD   CourseId    CourseGrade FailDate    FinalGrade
1           1           A           2017-05-19  A
1           2           I           2017-05-19  F
1           3           B           2017-05-19  B
1           4           I           2017-05-19  F
1           5           C           2017-05-19  C
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a SQL Agent job with an `UPDATE` statement making the change you desire, and schedule it for your desired date.

But really, you shouldn't be changing your grades :)

Comment: That's right - don't give them a chance to complete it, just fail'em all now! :-)

Comment: @BradC, Can i do that through C# application ??

Hehe, I made an application in C# and when the process i approved grade changes from **I** to **Null**, now there is a deadline and on that particular deadline I want grade to be change to **F** from **I**

Comment: If you have a C# application, you'll have to use one of the many methods out there to run a C# application on a schedule (windows scheduler, etc).

Comment: @BradC  not sure how can I do that because some process should be done the spot and this process should be done after 5/6 weeks.

Comment: @RDFozz I wish i could. That's how it should be :)